# Increase number in function and onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem for increase number in one unit when i call function and onclick event

**I have this:**

```
function caller() {    
    counter = 0;

    alert("ok" + counter);

    jQuery(".db_header_general" + number).click(function() {    
        alert("ok" + counter);
        counter++;
    });
}
```

In this case if i call the function always the alert tell me "0" and if i call function and use the event onclick yes the result it´s right 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 , etc , the problem it´s if i go and activate the function no continue from the last counter number and always show "0"

I need for example call function and show 1 ,2 ,3 and if event click it´s activate continue and add +1 from the last counter number , but the problem - and i can´t get works - . it´s no continue with the last number

**Also i try this**

```
function caller() {
    counter=0;

    alert("ok"+counter);

    jQuery(".db_header_general"+number).click(function() {
        alert("ok"+counter);
    });
    counter++;  
}
```

Using counter outside of click event, but also the same result and no works for me

Thank´s and the best regards for the help

Comment: place the counter variable outside the function. Currentyl, you are resetting it each time when you call the method.

Comment: @boulder_02 rights. And are you sure, that you want add handler of `click` event every time, when call `caller` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place counter outside the function. With current functionality when ever you call the function the counter value sets to 0. Do it like this

```
var counter = 0;

function caller ()
{
    // functionality 
    counter++;    
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but really if `counter` will be in global context - it is very bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
counter=0
```

gets executed every time you call your function because it's a local variable. So every time you call your function, you set the counter to 0. Make counter a global variable and it'll work.

Example added:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;
function caller(){
    alert("ok"+counter);
    jQuery(".myBtn").click(function() {
        alert("ok"+counter);
        counter++;
    });
}
```